# ordered pair of two real numers to find non-real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to find ordered pair $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $x^2+ax+b$ has non real roots, and whose cube is 343. That would mean $x^2+ax+b=7\Rightarrow x =\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4(b-7)}}{2}$ would I need to list all of them?

Comment: Cube of what? $a$? $b$?

Comment: it justs says find the ordered pair $(a,b)$ of real numbers for which $x^2+ax+b$ has non-real root whose cube is $343$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a polinomial with real coefficients s.t. one of it's roots is a complex solution of $x^3 = 343$.
If this is the case I think $(x-7(-\frac{1}{2}+ i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}))(x-7(-\frac{1}{2}- i\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}))= x^2+7x+49$ will do.

Remember that if $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, then for each $\zeta$ $n$th-root of unity we have that $\zeta\alpha$ is a root of $x^n=\alpha^n$

Comment: thanks for the reply pietropic, I didn't think about $x^3=343$ factorizing this would give $(x-7)(x^2+7x+49)$ thus the solution is $(7,49)$ right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the solution is (7,49). I just corrected my answer. Sorry if I was unclear